# How to use array include in multidimension array angular 2

Tags: angularjs, arrays, multidimensional-array

hi this is my array

```
this.testArray = [{ "office_id": "1", "officename": "sun" }, { "office_id": "2", "officename": "moon" }];
```

i want to check whether officename sun is there or not. I tried used **include** 
**this.testArray.includes("sun")**
but this will work for one dimension array( it will return true). how if I want to use it for this multidimension array.  it always return false.

** this.testArray.includes("sun") This will work with this array
**

```
this.testArray = ["sun","moon","stars" }];
```

it will return true it exist. but it is not working with my array the up one.

Comment: Can you give the sample multidimensional array you are using because the one you provided is not multidimensional

Answer (score 2):

Your array is not multidimensional. However you can do it like :

```
testArray.find(function(i){
   return (i.officename === 'sun');
});
```

Comment: i need to do it in my html, if it return true then the checkbox will be checked

Comment: you can create a function in your controller and call it from html. See this [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s8m6eyy7/)

Comment: o  i see, ok let me try

Comment: @user3431310 :  sure.. and if it helps please accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need a filter directly

```
| filter:{officename:'sun'}
```

or negative

```
| filter:{officename:'!sun'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can check value include or not by using [underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/) find function

```
this.testArra = [{ "office_id": "1", "officename": "sun" }, { "office_id": "2", "officename": "moon" }]

var temp =  _.find(this.testArra, function (o) { return o.officename==='sun2'; })
```

if temp "undefined" value not include, else value include

Comment: i need to do it in my html, if it return true then the checkbox will be checked

Answer (score 0):

you can use `find` method in javascript

**ES6 demo**

```js
var testArray = [{ "office_id": "1", "officename": "sun" }, { "office_id": "2", "officename": "moon" }];

var arr = testArray.find(o=> o.officename === "sun");

console.log(arr)
```

**ES5 demo**

```js
var testArray = [{ "office_id": "1", "officename": "sun" }, { "office_id": "2", "officename": "moon" }];

var arr = testArray.find(function(o){
   return  o.officename === "sun"
});

console.log(arr)
```